# sizeof union giving unexpected results

Tags: c++, unions

I have read that the sizeof union gives the largest size of member in the union.But when i do this:i'm getting unexpected results:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
union RecordType 
{
    int arr[9];
    double x;
};
int main()
{
    RecordType t;
    cout << sizeof(t);   //output is 40,instead of 36 (9*4bytes each)
}
```

why is the size 40 instead of 36 and even if i change the array to "int arr[10]",then sizeof gives the output as 40 (same as in the case of "int arr[9]),whats internally happening here?

Comment: The reason is memory alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `double` is a 64-bit type on your backend, the compiler will pad the size of the `union` with additional 32 bits or 4 bytes to align the `int`s and `double`. This way the `union` is aligned to 64 bits, regardless of what member is active.

If you created a union with a `float` instead, it would most likely have a size of `36` because no such alignment is necessary.

```cpp
union U 
{
    int arr[9];
    float x;
};
```

Note that this behavior is implementation defined and it is theoretically possible that a `double` is 32 bits large as well. So you should never rely on it.

Comment: Size and alignment are two different things. However, most platforms also align 64-bit floating point numbers to 8-byte boundaries.